# Using dictionary in Linq

Tags: c#

My code is as below

```
Object s = null;
var result = from r in records
         where MyDict.TryGetValue(r.Key, out s)
         select r;
```

How can I get the value of s from the first matching value ?

MyDict values

```
'a':'One'
'b':'Two'
```

Records have

```
'a'
'b'
```

I want to get the first value that matches in the dictionary

Comment: Please describe what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

```
var records = new List<string> { "a", "b" };
var myDict = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "a", "One"}, { "b", "Two" }, { "c", "Three" } };

var result = from r in records
                where myDict.ContainsKey(r)
                select myDict[r];
```

> I want to get the first value that matches in the dictionary

A dictionary does not allow to have duplicated keys.